# Access to controller variable from CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have @list  value in my controller and i have view where i m adding products.Form looks like  product_name  and  Add Button.I need to add all thees values to @list thought ajax request using coffe script or some other way, where i will not submit whole form.
How to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds quite strange...

First, any CoffeScript source will be compiled to Javascript, which is downloaded on the client side (in the browser). Your controller is running server-side, so it is only addressable through HTTP requests.

Nevertheless, an `@list` attribute is not persistent between two HTTP requests, so you will have to persist any change if you need to accumulate data, as you state in your question.

To achieve the AJAX call, I would recommend to use JQuery's helpers: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, or shortcuts like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, ...

The rest is Rails routing, as can be teached in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Hope this helps.